# Where exactly must I create the fr.lproj localization file, for example?

Tags: iphone, localization

Do you put it in "Other Resources"? Or "Resources-iPhone"? Or even in the Classes group? Or in the root of the project? What's the recommended place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be put anywhere, I put it near the nib files, so probably one of the first two places.